# handle views of relative layout on screen rotation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-orientation

My views get messed up on screen rotation. The data I enter in edit-text does not get erased. 
How could I handle my views on screen rotation?
[without rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0w85.png)

[with rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sW7Ma.png)

My code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    tools:context="com.example.juhi_gupta.pizza_corner.Home_Delivery_Activity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/home_page"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:text="Home Page"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#32127A"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/home_page"
        android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:text="Name :"
        android:textColor="#0000FF"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/name"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/name"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/option_3"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/option_3"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="enter full name"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:textColor="#228B22" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/items"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/name"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:text="@string/delivery_items"
        android:textColor="#0000FF"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/option_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/items"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/items"
        android:layout_below="@+id/items"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="@string/cheeze_burst"
        android:textColor="#32127A"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/option_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/option_7"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-1dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mobile"
        android:text="@string/mexican_wave"
        android:textColor="#32127A"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/option_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/option_2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/option_2"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/option_2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/option_2"
        android:text="@string/extravaganja"
        android:textColor="#32127A"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/option_4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/option_3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/option_1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/capsicum_twist"
        android:textColor="#32127A"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/option_5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/option_4"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText7"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-12dp"
        android:text="@string/choriza_pizza"
        android:textColor="#32127A"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/option_6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/option_4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mobile"
        android:text="@string/golden_corn"
        android:textColor="#32127A"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/option_7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rate"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/items"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:text="@string/paneer_crisp"
        android:textColor="#32127A"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/option_8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/option_7"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-1dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Sumit"
        android:text="@string/pineapple_pizza"
        android:textColor="#32127A"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quantity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/home_page"
        android:text="@string/quantity"
        android:textColor="#0000FF"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/quantity"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/quantity"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:ems="5"
        android:hint="@string/_1_to_1000"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="#228B22" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/quantity"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/home_page"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/home_page"
        android:text="@string/address"
        android:textColor="#0000FF"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/address"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/option_1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/enter_full_address"
        android:textColor="#228B22" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mobile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/date"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:text="@string/mobile_number"
        android:textColor="#0000FF"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="171dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/_10_digit_mobile_number"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="#228B22" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
        android:text="@string/delivery_date"
        android:textColor="#0000FF"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/date"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-18dp"
        android:ems="2"
        android:hint="@string/dd"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:textColor="#228B22" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-43dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText2"
        android:ems="4"
        android:hint="@string/yyyy"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:textColor="#228B22" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-40dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/rate"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rate"
        android:ems="2"
        android:hint="@string/mm"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:textColor="#228B22" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emailTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/emailText"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/quantity"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:text="@string/email_id"
        android:textColor="#0000FF"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/option_5"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/abc_gmail_com"
        android:textColor="#228B22" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Sumit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Cancel"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Cancel"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/option_2"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/option_2"
        android:background="#ffff00"
        android:onClick="open"
        android:text="@string/sumit"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/option_6"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:background="#ffff00"
        android:onClick="reset_all_input_parameters"
        android:text="@string/cancel"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/rate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Cancel"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Cancel"
        android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/option_2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/option_2"
        android:background="#ffff00"
        android:onClick="rate_page"
        android:text="@string/rate_us"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I don't want to fix the orientation of my app. i.e.:-

> setRequestedOrientation ( ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT ) ;  or
>   android:configChanges= " keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"

Comment: What do you mean by "without losing the data"?

Comment: data not in EditTexts but in TextViews? Because you said " data I enter in edit-text does not get erased."

Comment: *My views get messed up on screen rotation* Your views are messed up on portrait too. Start all over again and try it in more than 1 devices.

Comment: @0X0nosugar please suggest me a simple way.

Comment: Views get overlapped on landscape mode @0X0nosugar. I have used text views as subheadings.

Comment: Put your RelativeLayout inside a ScrollView or use different layout files for portrait and landscape mode (and follow @forpas's advice and test your layout file(s) thoroughly on different screen sizes/resolutions/orientations).

Comment: Your views are overapped in portrait mode too. The image you posted has nothing to do with your xml. **If** you don't know it, try another device with different dimensions in design preview.

Comment: create a layout-land resource folder and add your layout and adjust as per your need. you can set the layout design on time of orientation this method if that's your need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only use two layouts for each screen orientation in case you **really** need a different layout for both cases. I suppose that in your case is much better to have one layout that adjust to both cases.

When working with layout, consider using [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/) because it adjusts for all screen sizes and cases. Trust me, when I was using RelativeLayout and I was laze to learn about ConstraintLayout, I was being dumb because with ConstraintLayout you will gain a lot of time. Imagine coding one layout that will adjust to more than 20 screens.

For your case, you can use this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/home_page"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:text="@string/home_page"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="#32127A"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Name :"
            android:textColor="#0000FF"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/home_page" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="enter full name"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:textColor="#228B22"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/name"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/name"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/name"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/items"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:text="@string/delivery_items"
            android:textColor="#0000FF"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/name"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/radioGroupLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/items"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/items"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0">

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/option_1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/cheeze_burst"
                    android:textColor="#32127A"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/option_2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/mexican_wave"
                    android:textColor="#32127A"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/option_3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/extravaganja"
                    android:textColor="#32127A"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/option_4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/capsicum_twist"
                    android:textColor="#32127A"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </RadioGroup>

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/option_5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/choriza_pizza"
                    android:textColor="#32127A"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/option_6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/golden_corn"
                    android:textColor="#32127A"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/option_7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/paneer_crisp"
                    android:textColor="#32127A"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/option_8"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/pineapple_pizza"
                    android:textColor="#32127A"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </RadioGroup>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quantity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:text="@string/quantity"
            android:textColor="#0000FF"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radioGroupLinearLayout"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
            android:ems="5"
            android:hint="@string/_1_to_1000"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textColor="#228B22"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/quantity"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/quantity"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/quantity"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/quantity"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="@string/address"
            android:textColor="#0000FF"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/quantity"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/quantity" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/enter_full_address"
            android:textColor="#228B22"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/address"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/address"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/address"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mobile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:text="@string/mobile_number"
            android:textColor="#0000FF"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/address"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/address"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/_10_digit_mobile_number"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textColor="#228B22"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/mobile"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/mobile"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/mobile"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="@string/delivery_date"
            android:textColor="#0000FF"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mobile"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/mobile"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/dateLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/date"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/date"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/date"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="2"
                android:hint="@string/dd"
                android:inputType="date"
                android:textColor="#228B22" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="4"
                android:hint="@string/yyyy"
                android:inputType="date"
                android:textColor="#228B22" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="2"
                android:hint="@string/mm"
                android:inputType="date"
                android:textColor="#228B22" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/emailTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="@string/email_id"
            android:textColor="#0000FF"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/date"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/date"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/emailText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/abc_gmail_com"
            android:textColor="#228B22"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/emailTextView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/emailTextView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/emailTextView"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Sumit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:background="#ffff00"
            android:onClick="open"
            android:text="@string/sumit"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/Cancel"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/emailTextView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffff00"
            android:onClick="reset_all_input_parameters"
            android:text="@string/cancel"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Sumit"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/Sumit"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/Sumit"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/rate"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/rate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffff00"
            android:onClick="rate_page"
            android:text="@string/rate_us"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Cancel"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/Cancel"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/Cancel"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Element views not allowed here error is coming and no views are visible in the preview.

Comment: What API does your app is using?

Comment: minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27,     compileSdkVersion 27 using emulator containing android O using API 26

Comment: The code is fine here. It should be working, please post your full error.

Comment: Awesome, take a deeper look at [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/). I am sure you will not regret. Please upvote the answer if it was helpful, Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create another view for the same page in the editor. In the upper settings, choose orientation and create one for horizontal orientation. Set everything as you wish and you app will use the version you created when the orientation changes.

In orientation changes everything is rendered again in Android. However, as far as I know, you should now lose the `EditText` entries. If your `TextView`s are also set correctly in vertical mode, after setting up horizontal mode, they should also appear as expected.

Comment: Please elaborate on the suggestion given. Is there any simpler way to do it?

Comment: @learner well, to not to screw up the view, you need to use the modern tools that Google endorses, like not ListView but RecylerView; not RelativeLayout but ConstraintLayout etc. You already done some but if you still getting screwed-up view in orientation changes do what I say. To give more details, as for the latest version of Android studio, go to your XML, in the editor options right up your preview, find the rotation screen image (like in your phone) and click it. Choose "create Landscape variation" and do necessary bindings. Now you will see a corrected version in your app.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to obtain a landscape layout is creating a layout-land resource directory folder. 
Right click on

> Res folder >> New >> AndroidResoursceDirectory

A dialogue box appears in that select Resource type as layout from the drop-down and select orientation from qualifiers and add landscape and click ok. Hence a folder will create under the res folder "layout-land". 
Copy your current layout and paste in the layout-land folder and then edit your layout as per how you want to display it while orientation changes to the landscape mode.

By this method when you shift your app orientation from portrait to landscape you can create the same view designed for landscape mode.